# The function has been called 10 times but the decorator has only been called once. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

```
def call_counter(func):
    print('Called\n')
    def helper(x):
        helper.calls+=1
        return func(x)
    helper.calls=0
    return helper

@call_counter
def succ(x):
    return x+1

print(str(succ.calls)+'\n')
for i in range(10):
    print(succ.calls)
    succ(i)
print('\n')
print(succ.calls)
```

Comment: python noob here

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The output of your code is exactly what I'd expect. Can you give some more explanation in the question of what you expect and why? Maybe show the output you're getting and what you expected to get instead?

Comment: I don't understand why the decorator is called on the function only once. It should be called 10 times, right? One time for every iteration in the loop and therefore 'Called' should be printed 10 times. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You commented:

> I don't understand why the decorator is called on the function only once. It should be called 10 times, right? One time for every iteration in the loop and therefore 'Called' should be printed 10 times. What am I missing?

I think you are confusing runs of the decorator for runs of the wrapper function (named `helper` in your code). The decorator is only called once, when it gets passed the original function and returns the wrapper function, which is what gets stored as `succ` in your module. The wrapper is what gets called ten times by your loop.

When I run your code, this is the output I get:

```
Called

0

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9


10
```

Only the first two lines ("Called" and the empty line after it) come from the decorator call. You can see this if you run only the function definition, and not the loop. You'll see "Called" printed out immediately, even if you never call the function at all.

The zero at the top and the ten at the bottom are from the `print` statements you have at the top level. The numbers printed close together are the output of the loop, which prints the count of previous calls just before it makes each new call to the wrapped function.